# How do I escape Uri paths&query?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, escaping

I was doing something with redirecting and return urls and I notice something funky. I ran this line of code in visual studios immediate window.

```
Uri.EscapeUriString("/z?x=y&w="+Uri.EscapeUriString("/a?b=c&d=e"))
"/z?x=y&w=/a?b=c&d=e"
```

Ok this looks like the wrong escape. How on earth is my app suppose to know if d is part of the query string or part of the string meant for the url i want to redirect to later. So I tried UnescapeDataString and googled it just in case.

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString(Uri.EscapeDataString("a b+c"))
"a b+c"
```

It turns out I shouldnt use it becasue it doesnt decode '+' into space like it should

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("ab+c")
"ab+c"
```

If UnescapeDataString and EscapeUriString are both not right then how the heck am I suppose to escape uri's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`

Answer (score 1):

Yep, [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) is the way to go.

Here is an example. Code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace SO14450178
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Uri.EscapeUriString("/z?x=y&w="+Uri.EscapeUriString("/a?b=c&d=e")));
            string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("/z?x=y&w=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("/a?b=c&d=e"));
            Console.WriteLine(encoded);
            Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/z?x=y&w=/a?b=c&d=e
%2fz%3fx%3dy%26w%3d%252fa%253fb%253dc%2526d%253de
/z?x=y&w=%2fa%3fb%3dc%26d%3de
```

Note, that a single Decode decodes only one of the two Encode's as you would expect.